# Java Thread safe LinkedHashMap implementation?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, thread-safety

I need to make use of the `removeEldestEntry()` method of `LinkedHashMap`.

What's the easiest way I make use of `LinkedHashMap's` and the `removeEldestEntry()` method in a thread safe way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can anonymously extend `LinkedHashMap` to change the behavior of `removeEldestEntry(...)`, then wrap the instance of the anonymous class in a synchronized map.  You didn't mention what type parameters you require, so I'm using `<String, Integer>` in this example.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>() {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 12345L; // use something random or just suppress the warning
   @Override
   protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Entry<String, Integer> eldest) {
      return size() > MAX_SIZE; // how many entries you want to keep
   }               
});
```

Answer (score 4):

java.util.Collections.synchronizedMap(map) returns a synchronized (thread-safe) map backed by the specified map.